# Use BytesIO instead of NamedTemporaryFile with openpyxl

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I understand that with `openpyxl>=3.1` function `save_virtual_workbook` is gone and preferred solution is using `NamedTemporaryFile`.

I want it to be done without writing to filesystem, only in memory, just like `BytesIO` did.

Before update I had:

```
wb = Workbook()
populate_workbook(wb)
return BytesIO(save_virtual_workbook(wb))
```

Now I need:

```
wb = Workbook()
populate_workbook(wb)
tmpfile = NamedTemporaryFile()
wb.save(tmpfile.name)
return tmpfile
```

As in https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/tutorial.html?highlight=save#saving-as-a-stream

As I'm using django probably I could use `InMemoryUploadedFile` but I don't want to.

How can I use `BytesIO` or something similar in elegant fashion ie. without hacks and additional packages?

Comment: It's worth noting that openpyxl requires the use of temporary files anyway so the change was really just a simplication and, particularly in a web server context passing a real file means better decoupling of the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close, dude. Just pass a `io.BytesIO` buffer to the `wb.save` method.

```py
import openpyxl, io

# Create an in-memory bytes buffer, which is a file-like object
buffer = io.BytesIO()

# Create a workbook, do the shit you gotta do
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

# Save the workbook to the buffer, as if it were a file on disk opened for writing bytes
wb.save(buffer)

# Get all the bytes in the buffer.
# It's functionally the same as buffer.seek(0) then buffer.read()
buffer.getvalue()
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, `wb.save(buffer)` hangs indefinetely. I'll try it again in a minute, perhaps problem was somewhere else and I missed it.

Comment: yeah, problem was that I needed `buffer.seek(0)` before return, `buffer.getvalue()` doesn't work well with `FileResponse` but now it works fine, tx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly. But this is how I serve temporary files on the fly with django utilizing `io.BytesIO`.

```py
import io
from django.http import FileResponse

def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
    buffer = io.BytesIO(bytes(create_some_file(), "utf-8"))

    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename=f"the_file.format")
```

Comment: problem is that without `save_virtual_workbook` openpyxl is not compatible with this solution, afaik